# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows when run Tomcat, GlassFish

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, glassfish

```
When I tried to start GlassFish, Tomcat 
gives me this error in the log

______________________________________________________________________

Error as follows
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fef6a43bdc, pid=5860, tid=4776
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [chtbrkg.dll+0x23bdc]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
______________________________________________
```

I set the java path properly, java version is JDK 1.7, OS is Windows 7 and GlassFish is 4.1.1, Tomcat virsion is 8

Any idea to fix this error

Comment: Thanks for the reply for all, finally I had to format the machine after doing lots of changes. Now works fine, can run GlassFish. Tried many ways but could not be solved until I reinstall Windows.